# any proper subgroup is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

We need to prove that any proper subgroup of $C_{p^\infty}$ is cyclic of order $p^n$ for some $n$ ($p$ is prime).
 Consider the chain

> $0\subset C_p \subset C_{p^2}\subset \dots$

which has $C_{p^\infty}$ as its union. Let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $C_{p^\infty}$. $g$ is in some $C_{p^n}$, but not in $H$. $|g|=p^n$. Consider $h$ in $H$. $|h|<|g|=p^n$.

Then I got stuck here and don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: You almost have it: since $\;H\;$ is proper there is $\;n\in\Bbb N\; $ s.t. $\;C_{p^n}\le H\;$ but $\;C_{p^{n+1}}\rlap{\;\;/}\le H\;$ , so in fact it *must* be $\;C_{p^n}=H\;$ (why?)

Comment: @DonAntonio: The element g which is in C(p^(n+1)) but not in C(p^n) generates C(p^n+1), right? thus, the order of g is p^(n+1), while order of h is P^n... though, how do I proceed further?

Comment: I'm not sure why you talk of the element(s) that belong to $\;C_{p^{n+1}}\setminus H\;$...just use that $\;H\;$ is a subgroup, so if there exists $\;x\in H\setminus C_{p^n}\;$ then **it must** be that $\;ord(x)>p^n\;$ and thus $\;ord(x)\ge p^{n+1}\;$ , which means $\;C{p^{n+1}}\le H\;$ , contradiction...I think this solves the problem, yet I'm not completely sure whether this addresses your doubt.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Could you, please, check up my solution?
Let H is a proper subgroup of Cp∞, i.e. there exists at least one element g∈Cp∞ s.t. g is not in H. Let h∈H. If |h|≥|g|, g∈C(p^n), then C(p^n) is a subgroup of H, g∈H, which is a contradiction. Now, |h|<|g|=p^n: |h|≤p^n. It follows that H ≤ C(p^(n-1)), which is cyclic. Thus, any proper subgroup H in Cp∞ is cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

It is not hard to see that $C_{p^{\infty}}=\{\frac{a}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\,|a\in\mathbb Z,n\in \mathbb N \}$. Let $H$ be proper subgroup of $C_{p^{\infty}}$. First, we claim that if $\frac{a}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\in H$ and $(a,p)=1$, then  $\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\in H$.

There exits $r,s\in\mathbb Z$ such that $ra+sp^n=1$. We can conclude that $\frac{1-sp^n}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\in H$ and so $\frac{1}{p^n}-s+\mathbb Z\in H$ and the claim is proved. Now, we show that there exist $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $H=\langle\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\rangle$. Assume that $n$ is the largest number such that $\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z$. Note that if $n$ doesnt exist, then we can infer that $H=C_{p^{\infty}}$. It is obvious that $\langle\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\rangle\subseteq H$. Suppose that $\frac{b}{p^m}+\mathbb Z\in H \setminus\langle\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\rangle$ and so $\frac{1}{p^m}+\mathbb Z\in H$. Since $n$ is largest number, $m<n$. Therefore, we have $\frac{1}{p^m}+\mathbb Z\in \langle\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z\rangle$ as, $\frac{1}{p^m}+\mathbb Z=p^{n-m}(\frac{1}{p^n}+\mathbb Z)$. It is contradiction.